# Seized Calipers That Move - Worth Keeping?

Tags: honda, civic, caliper

I have a 2009 Honda Civic Si. I took off the left rear caliper and found it to be really difficult to push in (it wasn't moving at all at first), as compared to the right rear caliper. Yes, I used a proper tool and know it needs to rotate.

Is it worth trying to just put new pads / rotors in if the caliper moves (poorly)? Or is it likely to seize up again soon? I can't seem to find a "definitive answer" online. I am not too concerned about the money, but I would rather not do extra work if there is a REALLY high chance that it's not necessary.

Side note: The rubber boot doesn't seem to fold as cleanly as the one on the other side, but I don't understand how those don't tear anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a big difference in the effort required to retract the piston I would replace the caliper. Prior to doing so I would verify the issue isn't a bad brake hose. It doesn't happen often but sometimes  a hose fails internally. The high pressure created by the master cylinder forces fluid in but the pressure isn't released when the pedal is released. To eliminate the hose as the problem, disconnect the hose from the caliper. If the piston moves freely the hose is at least suspect.

Comment: Opening the bleed valve might be an easier way to check the hose. Not so much liquid spilling around etc.

Comment: That's an excellent point @sweber - can always grab a brake-bleed hose and bottle so that there is no need to re-bleed after this test.